# Parse JSON into List in Android Studio [java]

Tags: java, android, json

I'm new to Java, now I want to parse data from API Request. I have tested all the classes in JSONParse but no luck.

I use the JSONParser class made by 
[Mini Sharma](http://mrbool.com/how-to-use-json-to-parse-data-into-android-application/28944)

and also I prepare a JSON from URL it returns:

```
{
        "code": "100",
        "message": "success",
        "data": [
           {
               "FullName": "Marcelius Dagpin",
               "Email": "mardagz@gmail.com",
               "Android_ID": "e88244s1606091f6"
           }
        ],
        "time": "0.88044500350952 ms"
}
```

My approach:

```
class PostRegistration extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog pgDialog;
    //On Execute Progress
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pgDialog.setMessage("Please wait while processing your registration");
        pgDialog.setTitle("Processing");
        pgDialog.show();
        pgDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean status) {
        if(pgDialog.isShowing()) {
            pgDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    //Running on background
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            JSONArray json = jsonParser.getJSONFromURL(args[0]); //http://localhost/dev/?request=post&type=user&value=VALUEHERE
            JSONObject jsono = json.getJSONObject(0);

            Log.d("Tag", jsono.toString());
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

I encounter the error when running this code.

Here's the log:

```
    02-27 02:00:00.077    2180-2180/com.sprikiwiki_lab.dev.practice1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sprikiwiki_lab.dev.practice1, PID: 2180
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sprikiwiki_lab.dev.practice1/com.sprikiwiki_lab.dev.practice1.RegistrationActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2318)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
            at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
            at android.util.Log.println_filter(Log.java:105)
            at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:166)
            at com.sprikiwiki_lab.dev.practice1.RegistrationActivity.onCreate(RegistrationActivity.java:79)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 02:00:01.367    2180-2180/com.sprikiwiki_lab.dev.practice1 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2180 SIG: 9
```

and to be honest.

can anyone help me or suggest something.

Thanks

Comment: Do you initialise or create ProgressDialog?

Comment: Post logs from your log cat

Comment: Your issue comes from RegistrationActivity

Comment: You try print null Could you post RegistrationActivity class?

Comment: yes. same thing that error appear.

Comment: Post code of RegistrationActivity I will help you

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak i just post it here http://paste.ubuntu.com/10433723/ :) thank you so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71818/discussion-between-konrad-krakowiak-and-mardagz).

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak you online master? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I analysed your code and I found a few issue. I will describe it step by step:

As first in android, when you want to connect with internet you have to register permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

The second point is the way how do you set `DATA_URL`

here you initialise one variable

```
private static String DATA_URL = null;
```

And here you want to set it

```
   try {
        //...
        String DATA_URL = "http://dev.sprikiwiki-lab.com/?request=get&uid=1";
    }catch (Exception e) {
      //...
    }
```

But you create new variable - you have to remove `String` like below:

```
   try {
        //...
        DATA_URL = "http://dev.sprikiwiki-lab.com/?request=get&uid=1";
    }catch (Exception e) {
        //...
    }
```

Additionally you can remove static :)

The next issue is inside of getJSONFromUrl method. You passed url as parameter but you do with this nothing. Change line blow:

```
     HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet();
```

with this:

```
     HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
```

Last issue is on the end of your method. You create `new JSONArray(builder);`. You should create newJSONObject(builder) here as is show code below:

```
     //Parse string to JSON object
    try {
        jarray = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    //Return json to array
    return jarray;
```

Additionally you have to change type of  `jarray` to `JSONObject` and returned type of `getJSONFromURL` method

Comment: you online mate? :) @Konrad Krakowiak

Comment: yes come to chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71818/discussion-between-konrad-krakowiak-and-mardagz

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

*=>* if string start with `{` means string a `JSONObject`

*=>* if string start with `[` means string a `JSONArray`

Posted json string with question is starting with `{` .

Need to change `getJSONFromURL` method:

**1.** Convert server response String to `JSONObject` instead of `JSONArray`:

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(<response_string>);
```

**2.** Change `getJSONFromURL` method retunr type to JSONObject from JSONArray

**3.** Get `getJSONFromURL` response in `JSONObject`:

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromURL(args[0]);
```

Comment: what do you by `<response_string>`? :)

Comment: @mardagz : `<response_string>` means pass `builder.toString()` as in provided tutorial

Comment: @mardagz: `NullPointerException: println needs a message` is another issue and my answer help you in parsing json string  because currently you are doing wrong. error occurring probably due to server response is null

Answer (score 0):

Line 79 of you RegistrationActivity is trying to print NULL to logcat. Make sure you not sending a NULL string to the Log.d() method.

Comment: Yes, exactly coz the JSON did not parse well.

Comment: But how to pass your parssed json to activity

Comment: Is this AsycTask declared inside the the RegistrationActivity and line 79 is displayed above?